# How to model inbox

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

How would ago about modelling the data if I have a web app for messaging and I expect the user to either see all the messages ordered by date, or see the messages exchanged with a specific contact, again ordered by date.

Should I have two tables, called "global_inbox" and "contacts_inbox" where I would add each message to both?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE global_inbox(user_id int, timestamp timestamp, 
                          message text, PRIMARY KEY(user_id, timestamp)

CREATE TABLE inbox(user_id int, contact_id int, 
                   timestamp timestapm, message text, 
                   PRIMARY KEY(user_id, contact_id, timestamp)
```

This means that every message should be copied 4 times, 2 for sender and 2 for receiver. Does it sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's reasonable.
You need some modification.

- Inbox table : If a user have many contact and every contact send message, then a huge amount of data will be inserted into a single partition (user_id). So add contact_id to partition key.

Updated Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE inbox (
     user_id int, 
     contact_id int, 
     timestamp timestamp, 
     message text, 
     PRIMARY KEY((user_id, contact_id), timestamp)
);
```

- global_inbox : Though It's global inbox, a huge amount of data can be inserted into a single partition (user_id). So add more key to partition key to more distribution.

Updated Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE global_inbox (
     user_id int,
     year int,
     month int, 
     timestamp timestamp, 
     message text, 
     PRIMARY KEY((user_id,year,month), timestamp)
);
```

Here you can also add also add week to partition key, if you have huge data in a single partition in a week. Or remove month from partition key if you think not much data will insert in a year.

Answer (score 1):

In term of queries performance, Yes it sounds good for me. Apache cassandra is really built in for this kind of data modeling. We build table to satisfy queries. This is the process called 'Denormalization' in Cassandra paradigm. This will increase queries performance. You have duplicated data but the main goal is to have fast queries.